# Keyboard [Enter Key] binding giving Exception in Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

We are having an issue in Vaadin, When the user hits the Enter Key to save the page's data below error comes.

I tried everything to debug the issue in the java code. But when I opened the developer tool I saw the following error and I don't know how to solve this issue.

```
client-5C40CA4B9D1F93A241DF9189632E0919.cache.js:212 
    
   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_content')
   ZC @ client-5C40CA4B9D1F93A241DF9189632E0919.cache.js:212
   vaadin-grid-keyboard-navigation-mixin.html.js:332 
    
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_content')
at HTMLElement._onInteractionKeyDown (vaadin-grid-keyboard-navigation-mixin.html.js:332)
at HTMLElement._onKeyDown (vaadin-grid-keyboard-navigation-mixin.html.js:113)
```

Please help.

Comment: If you think it is a bug in Vaadin's Grid component, report it in github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues instead of StackOverflow. And code that reproduces the issue in the ticket.

Comment: Could you please update your question with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: What is it that you are editing? Does the problem occur regardless of which type of data you have changed? Is the Enter about your Grid's editor save, or do you have the Enter shortcut tied to some separate save button that saves more than your changes to the Grid?

Comment: There is no specific data,  there are only 3 text fields we are filling and only one save button and that button is having this.calculateAmountOwingButton.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);  this line. no other button has it.

Comment: I seriously don't know which code is creating this issue. Because It is not coming in my local computer but only on production. I tried every possible way to create this issue. Even when I myself test on production I don't get this issue but someone else does it randomly appears. This is the reason I came here. I commented all the code on the click event and only by one enabled. But how would I know we are not seeing this error anyway on our local computer.

Comment: Grid also has some built-in keyboard shortcut handling, see e.g. https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/blob/master/src/vaadin-grid-keyboard-navigation-mixin.html#L124

But have you tried `mvn vaadin:clean-frontend` and to recompile, in case your client-side state has got messed up somehow?

Comment: Or, if your Vaadin 14 version is too old to contain that goal, check out this troubleshooting guide: https://mvysny.github.io/Vaadin-troubleshooting/

Comment: These two suggestions can be the possibility. I will look into both of these Suggestions. I am extremely thankful to you guys for you all giving me some time on this and helping. I will let you all tomorrow.